# Good t-SNE or bad t-SNE?

Tags: statistics, tsne

I have used tsne to visualise a large dataset and it has produced the following graph. I need help interpreting it, as I have never seen a tsne graph like this before!

I am aware that not much overlapping data is a good thing, but I have rarely seen more than a few clusters. Has something gone wrong here? Or are there just a lot of clusters in this dataset.

Thanks. P

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that tSNE isn't the only dimensionality reduction tool out there. Use the algorithm which best fits your data.

Comment: A bit of advice: the t-SNE output depends heavily on the perplexity parameter chosen.  I'd recommend always giving the perplexity that the picture was generated at.

Answer (score 3):

t-SNE is notoriously fickle.  I would advise you read this short article [How to Use t-SNE Effectively](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) before you invest too much time trying to interpret the plots.  In case you don't read it, you'll find that your t-SNE plot will change considerably based on your iterations, and perplexity.  You'll find that distance between clusters aren't accurate and that cluster sizes aren't accurate too.  t-SNE is a cool data reduction too, but often takes multiple runs to get a "good" plot.  Laurens van der Maatan even suggest that running multiple iterations and picking the one with the lowest KL-divergence is perfectly okay.  This is due to the fact that t-SNE is non-convex so you won't necessarily find a global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, even more extreme looking. The data is from a depression screening survey as part of the [Health and Nutrition Examination Survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr1Qk.png). It's from "2017 - March 2020 Pre-pandemic" --> "Questionnaire Data" --> "Mental Health - Depression Screener". It has eleven columns, presumably one per question, and ~8k rows. Dropping NaN's, ~5k rows. I tried filling NaN's with mean, but the same plot occurred.

[image: curvy t-SNE plot]

The fix wasn't the perplexity, but rather an index column was in the data. After dropping,

[image: t-SNE no curvy line]

No clear clusters, but looks a lot better.